# What is the difference between the two expressions?

Tags: c#, boolean-operations

I was wondering what is the difference between the two approaches, between `|=` and simply `=` although the same result. I don't know what is the difference

This is for educational purposes.

```cs
public int ValueA { get; set; }
public int ValueB { get; set; }
bool someBool { get; private set; }

#region using_|=
someBool |= ValueA >= ValueB;
#endregion

#region using_basic_=
someBool = ValueA >= ValueB;
#endregion
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#compound-assignment

Comment: `someBool |= ValueA >= ValueB;`->
`someBool = someBool |  ValueA >= ValueB;`

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen it, but it seems to work like the self incrementing `+=` operator, except for booleans.  So `|=` means, "set the variable to the logical result of the original value OR the right hand value".

So, in the code below, `b` becomes true because it was initially true, and that initial value was then compared to false.  And true OR false = true.

```
var b = true;
b |= false;
Console.WriteLine(b); // true
```

But here, `b` is just simply set to true.

```
b = false;
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

And, as I suspected, there is also an `&=` operator.